# python3 exception invalid syntax error

Tags: python, exception

I recently started learning python3, and I am trying to write an exception. 
I have this line, which is a list of words. 
I want to match the word create to the list, sometimes it's there sometimes its not. When it's not there I get this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "sub_process.py", line 17, in <module>
if (line.index("create")):
ValueError: 'create' is not in list
```

and I am fine with that. This is expected. So I thought if I wrote an exception to it the script could just continue on and keep doing stuff. So I an exception below and all its suppose to do is nothing. Catch the error and continue on.

```
line = line.split()

if line.index("create"):
    print("basd");
except ValueError:
    print("123");
```

But everytime i try to compile this I get syntax error at "except" and I am not sure why. It looks perfectly normal compared against all the tutorials that I could find.

Comment: Why the semicolons?

Comment: can i do it without try?

Comment: @AndrewL old habit left over from c++ i think. and IDLE doesn't complain.

Comment: @D.Zou not if you want to catch the exception.

Comment: @leaf is try like if with exceptions? what makes try work with exception but if doesn't?

Comment: @D.Zou The [python docs](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/errors.html) could probably explain better than I could.

Answer (score 4):

Rather than using `index`, you should just be using the `in` operator, which returns a simple boolean:

```
if "create" in line:
    print("basd")
else:
    print("123")
```

This will not raise an exception so there is no need for try/except.

Comment: Hmm, didn't think of that. +1 But what about his other print statement?

Comment: This is a good idea, but I am trying to simplify my code and I need the index number as well. rather then doing "if the word is there and then if the word is at index location" I thought it would be easier if I just did "if the word is at index location". In my use cases it will either be there or or it won't be.

Answer (score 1):

You need to add `try` before the `if` statement:

```
line = line.split()
try: # added 'try'
    if line.index("create"):
        print("basd");
except ValueError:
    print("123");
```

Also note, you don't need the semicolons at the end of statements, and it is generally frowned upon when they are used in that way.

As an alterintave to @Rosemans solution, you can do that all on one line:

```
print('basd') if "create" in line else print("123")
```

Answer (score 1):

if/except is not a valid construct. Use try/except:

```
line = line.split()

try:
    if line.index('create'):
        print('basd')

except ValueError:
    print("123")
```

Alternatively, you could avoid the exception and the try/except altogether:

```
line = line.split()

if 'create' in line:
    print('basd')

else:
    print("123")
```

Answer (score 0):

```
#use try block..
line = line.split()
try:
    if line.index("create"):
        print("basd")
except ValueError:
    print("123")
```

Comment: Please refrain from posting code-only answers. Add some comments and/or explanation so that future readers understand what you are doing.

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the question, [including an explanation](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion.